# Checking if the given set is a basis, representing a matrix in such basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that the set $S$ is a basis of vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ and to represent $x$ in that basis, where
$$S=\left\{s_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
s_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
s_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
s_4=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
$$x=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 7 \\
2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.$$
I believe I have correctly proved linear independence:

Let $\sum_{i=1}^4\alpha_is_i=0\left(=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right)$
\begin{align*}
\implies \alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_4&=0\\ \nonumber
\alpha_1+\alpha_3+\alpha_4&=0 \\ \nonumber
\alpha_2&=0 \\ \nonumber
\alpha_4&=0 \\ \nonumber
\implies \alpha_i&=0,\;i=1, 2 ,3 ,4. \nonumber
\end{align*}
Therefore, vectors of the given set $S$ are linearly independant.

When it comes to representing $x$ in this basis, we know that each vector has unique coordinates $\xi_i$ in a given basis: $x=\sum_{i=1}^4\xi_is_i.$
With a method analogous to which I used for proving linear independence, I have found that
\begin{align*}
\xi_1=7,\\
\xi_2=2,\\
\xi_3=-3,\\
\xi_4=3,
\end{align*}
Therefore, we can write $x$ as
\begin{equation}
x=7s_1+2s_2-3s_3+3s_4.\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{equation}

**My questions are:**

(i) Have I correctly proved linear independence?

(ii) For $S$ to be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, besides linear independence, it also has to span $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$. I know intuitively that this is true, because all the vectors are linearly independant and $|S|=\dim \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}=4$, but how do I prove this?

(iii) Is the way I've written $x$ in (1) sufficient? Could it perhaps be written as $x=\begin{pmatrix}
7\\
2\\
-3\\
3\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) Yes, your proof of linear independence is correct. You have verified that if the linear combination is equal to zero, then the coefficients must be zero, which the definition of linear independence.

(ii) There's a theorem that states that every set of $n$ linearly independent vectors in a vector space $V$ with $\dim(V)=n$ is a basis.

(iii) The way you wrote $x$ in (1) is sufficient. It can also be written the way you suggest in your question if it's understood that this is with respect to the basis $S$. However, I personally think the way you wrote it originally is clearer, since it emphasizes which (non-standard) basis you're using. I prefer to reserve writing vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $n$-tuples only with respect to the standard basis.